# Problem after adding maatwebsite excel package to existing laravel 5.7 project

Tags: laravel, controller, maatwebsite-excel

After installing maatwebsite as per the installation guide, No functions in Home controller is working, but other controllers are working.Tried changing the name of the controller,but no use.

During installation i got some warnings :

```
   Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Console\Kernel" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Console\Kernel.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Console\Kernel.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Exceptions\Handler" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Exceptions\Handler.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\Handler.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\Controller" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\HomeController" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Kernel" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Kernel.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Kernel.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Providers\AppServiceProvider" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Providers\EventServiceProvider" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\User" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\Exceptions\cms\app\User.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/hrms/app\User.php", the first will be used.
```

Comment: have you checked file duplicate not exist in your app. try composer dump-autoload once

Comment: That’s because you have classes under the same directory with the same namespace and name for which composer is attempting to autoload. Make sure you namespace your classes properly.

Comment: Yes there was a duplicate file. Sorry for that :( And thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

i also get the same issue and i did the following

```
 1. Delete vendor/ 
 2. Delete composer.lock 
 3. composer install
```